# How to use variable increment and concatenate it to each child node using xslt

Tags: xslt

I need some help with an XSLT code which I am trying to build. The below XML code has multiple child nodes  which I need to transform to a concatenated value of 'variable'_(Filename value). My sample XML is below,

```
<Attachments>
    <AttachFile>
        <FilContentType>application/pdf; name=docxyz1.pdf</FilContentType>
        <FileName>docxyz1.pdf</FileName>
    </AttachFile>
    <AttachFile>
        <FilContentType>application/pdf;name=docxyz2.pdf</FilContentType>
        <FileName>docxyz2.pdf</FileName>
    </AttachFile>
    <AttachFile>
        <FilContentType>application/pdf; name=docxyz3.pdf</FilContentType>
        <FileName>docxyz3.pdf.pdf</FileName>
    </AttachFile>
</Attachments>
```

The transformed output needs to be as below

```
<Attachments>
    <AttachFile>
        <FilContentType>application/pdf; name=docxyz1.pdf</FilContentType>
        <FileName>1_docxyz1.pdf</FileName>
    </AttachFile>
    <AttachFile>
        <FilContentType>application/pdf;name=docxyz2.pdf</FilContentType>
        <FileName>2_docxyz2.pdf</FileName>
    </AttachFile>
    <AttachFile>
        <FilContentType>application/pdf; name=docxyz3.pdf</FilContentType>
        <FileName>3_docxyz3.pdf.pdf</FileName>
    </AttachFile>
</Attachments>
```

I tried calling a template and using for-each but my logic is incorrect. My XSLT code is below:

```
 <xsl:variable name="Count" select="count(/Attachments/AttachFile/FileName)"/>
<xsl:variable name="i" select="1"></xsl:variable>


<xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Attachments"/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Attachments">
    <Attachments>
        <xsl:for-each select="./Attachments/AttachFile">
            <AttachFile>
                <FilContentType><xsl:value-of select="FilContentType"/></FilContentType>

            <xsl:call-template name="Increment">
                <xsl:with-param name="i" select="1"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Count" select="$Count"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            </AttachFile>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </Attachments>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Increment">
    <xsl:param name="i"/>
    <xsl:param name="Count"/>
    <xsl:if test="$Count > $i">
        <Filename>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat($i,'_',FileName)"/> 
        </Filename>
        <xsl:call-template name="Increment">
            <xsl:with-param name="i" select="$i + 1"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="Count" select="$Count"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks

Comment: My apologies, I did not post my question properly. I have updated my post with the XSLT code. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for improving the question.  Down/close votes retracted.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't it be simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FileName">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:number count="AttachFile" format="1_"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Applied to your example, the result will be:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Attachments>
  <AttachFile>
    <FilContentType>application/pdf; name=docxyz1.pdf</FilContentType>
    <FileName>1_docxyz1.pdf</FileName>
  </AttachFile>
  <AttachFile>
    <FilContentType>application/pdf;name=docxyz2.pdf</FilContentType>
    <FileName>2_docxyz2.pdf</FileName>
  </AttachFile>
  <AttachFile>
    <FilContentType>application/pdf; name=docxyz3.pdf</FilContentType>
    <FileName>3_docxyz3.pdf.pdf</FileName>
  </AttachFile>
</Attachments>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9y

Comment: Thanks Michael for the answer! But I am trying to rename each filename node value depending on the child node occurrence. For example, the first child node which has a value docxyz1.pdf needs to be transformed to 1_docxyz1.pdf, the second child node value docxyz2.pdf needs to be transformed to 2_docxyz2.pdf and so on.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what it does?

Comment: @AshishKumar: This answer's output matches your requested XML.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks so much, Michael!